# How can I make Spring interrupt a file upload after a specific size?

Tags: java, spring

In a Java web-app built upon Spring, one can upload files. The size of these file-uploads is limited in length via the following bean property in `dispatcher-servlet.xml` :

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="7000000" /><!-- amount is in Bytes -->
</bean>
```

When an uploaded file is bigger than the defined limit, a `org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException` is thrown as expected.

The problem is that uploads above the limit will complete and THEN throw the exception, instead of throwing the exception ***as soon as the limit is reached***.

For a limit of 7MB's, it is possible to upload a 1GB file (and then get an error message) - which is an issue.

How can I force Spring to interrupt the download ***as soon as*** the specified length is reached ?

Note : I'm not interested in client-side validation which is way too easy to bypass ; the goal is to avoid a DOS via server resource depletion (e.g.: a malicious actor uploads 100 1GB files via 100 botnet slaves, at the same time, on a poor little VPS with limited resources).

Thanks for any help !! :)

Comment: Did you try: http.spring.multipart.max-file-size: in your app.properties? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/MultipartProperties.html

Comment: No, because this project is not spring-boot enabled. As you can see from the .xml configuration, it's a rather old project :) Yet it is Spring 4 and I'm pretty sure that the upload interruption can be done, I just can't figure out how..